# Query records created between time, regardless of the day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I query for records between 12:45:00 and 12:45:59 in Rails?

The dateTime for my record is  `Mon, 06 Nov 2022 12:12:10.000000000 EST -05:00` but when I run `find_by("datetime_field::time BETWEEN '12:12:00' AND '12:13:00'")`, it returns `nil`.

Datebase: PostgresQL

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a time zone issue. If you are doing things in the "normal" Rails way, your column is probably of type `timestamp without time zone` and the timestamps are stored in UTC. You could run this to see what the times are:

```
YourModel.select("datetime_field::time as time").map(&:time)
```

You will probably see an array of UTC times, and your `find_by` will work correctly if you use UTC times instead of EST times.